# Angular pass route data from inside component

Tags: angular, typescript

What i want to do is pass data to route from inside component..

in app component ts i have this

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (event instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
    let current_route = event.state.root.firstChild;
    const title = current_route?.data.title;
    this.titleService.setTitle(title);
  }
});
```

Then routes like this

```
  { path: 'confirm-registration/:code', component: HomeComponent,canActivate:[HomeGuard],data:{title:'title.landing_page'} },
  { path: 'u/:user', component: ProfileComponent},
```

And in profile component i need to pass title to route somehow..

I tried this to put this inside ngOnInit, but it isnt working

```
this.router.navigate([decodeURI(this.router.url)],{state: {title: "Test Title"}});
```

So i would like to ask if it is possible to achieve this somehow.

#### EDIT

I tried following

```
let currentRoutes = this.router.config;
currentRoutes[1].data = {title: res.data.name};
this.router.resetConfig(currentRoutes);
this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);
```

it changes data successfully but there is problem so it just keep navigate infinitely

Answer (score 0):

That should not be inside ngOnInit(), its a lifecycle hook.

If you are routing on a button click, then better write a function to run on the click event, and inside that function, this line should be pasted.

Comment: no, i want to execute this everytime user access ProfileComponent(even when he loads site for first time - without routerlink)